# How do I make a bazel `sh_binary` target depend on other binary targets?

Tags: bazel

I have set up bazel to build a number of CLI tools that perform various database maintenance tasks.  Each one is a `py_binary` or `cc_binary` target that is called from the command line with the path to some data file: it processes that file and stores the results in a database.

Now, I need to create a dependent package that contains data files and shell scripts that call these CLI tools to perform application-specific database operations.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to depend on the existing `py_binary` or `cc_binary` targets from a new package that only contains `sh_binary` targets and data files.  Trying to do so results in an error like:

```
ERROR: /workspace/shbin/BUILD.bazel:5:12: in deps attribute of sh_binary rule //shbin:run: py_binary rule '//pybin:counter' is misplaced here (expected sh_library)
```

Is there a way to call/depend on an existing bazel binary target from a shell script using `sh_binary`?

I have implemented a full example here:
https://github.com/psigen/bazel-mixed-binaries

---

**Notes:**

I cannot use `py_library` and `cc_library` instead of `py_binary` and `cc_binary`. This is because **(a)** I need to call mixes of the two languages to process my data files and **(b)** these tools are from an upstream repository where they are already designed as CLI tools.

I also cannot put all the data files into the CLI tool packages -- there are multiple application-specific packages and they cannot be mixed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can either create a genrule to run these tools as part of the build, or create a sh_binary that depends on the tools via the `data` attribute and runs them them.

### The genrule approach

This is the easier way and lets you run the tools as part of the build.

```
genrule(
    name = "foo",
    tools = [
        "//tool_a:py",
        "//tool_b:cc",
    ],
    srcs = [
        "//source:file1",
        ":file2",
    ],
    outs = [
        "output_file1",
        "output_file2",
    ],
    cmd = "$(location //tool_a:py) --input=$(location //source:file1) --output=$(location output_file1) && $(location //tool_b:cc) < $(location :file2) > $(location output_file2)",
)
```

### The sh_binary approach

This is more complicated, but lets you run the sh_binary either as part of the build (if it is in a `genrule.tools`, similar to the previous approach) or after the build (from under `bazel-bin`).

In the `sh_binary` you have to data-depend on the tools:

```
sh_binary(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["my_shbin.sh"],
    data = [
        "//tool_a:py",
        "//tool_b:cc",
    ],
)
```

Then, in the `sh_binary` you have to use the so-called "Bash runfiles library" built into Bazel to look up the runtime-path of the binaries. This library's documentation is [in its source file](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/8fa6b3fe71f91aac73c222d8082e75c69d814fa7/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash#L15-L64).

The idea is:

1. the sh_binary has to [depend on a specific target](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/8fa6b3fe71f91aac73c222d8082e75c69d814fa7/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash#L29)
2. you have to [copy-paste some boilerplate code](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/8fa6b3fe71f91aac73c222d8082e75c69d814fa7/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash#L38-L59) to the top of the sh_binary (reason is described [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/8fa6b3fe71f91aac73c222d8082e75c69d814fa7/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash#L34-L36))
3. then you can [use the `rlocation` function](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/8fa6b3fe71f91aac73c222d8082e75c69d814fa7/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash#L63) to look up the runtime-path of the binaries

For example your `my_shbin.sh` may look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# --- begin runfiles.bash initialization ---
...
# --- end runfiles.bash initialization ---

path=$(rlocation "__main__/tool_a/py")
if [[ ! -f "${path:-}" ]]; then
  echo >&2 "ERROR: could not look up the Python tool path"
  exit 1
fi
$path --input=$1 --output=$2
```

The `__main__` in the rlocation path argument is the name of the workspace. Since your `WORKSPACE` file does not have a "workspace" rule in, which would define the workspace's name, Bazel will use the default workspace name, which is `__main__`.

Comment: Thanks @Laszlo, the second approach is working great!

Comment: Thanks for your edit suggestions [psigen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044807/psigen)! Apparently it was rejected. I edited the original post with the bugfix for the shell script.

Comment: If you are trying to use the second approach, make sure the boilerplate you copy paste into your shell script is from master, it has changed a bit since this post was first written.

Comment: I tried to use the same way to start a java binary target in Bazel, but unfortunately i got an error `Cannot locate runfiles directory. (Set $JAVA_RUNFILES to inhibit searching.)`. Where may i find those java runfiles?

Answer (score 8):

A clean way to do this is to use [`args` and `$(location)`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#binary.args):

Contents of `BUILD`:

```
py_binary(
    name = "counter",
    srcs = ["counter.py"],
    main = "counter.py",
)

sh_binary(
    name = "run",
    srcs = ["run.sh"],
    data = [":counter"],
    args = ["$(location :counter)"],
)
```

Contents of `counter.py` (your tool):

```
print("This is the counter tool.")
```

Contents of `run.sh` (your bash script):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eEuo pipefail

counter="$1"
shift

echo "This is the bash script, about to call the counter tool."
"$counter"
```

And here's a demo showing the bash script calling the Python tool:

```
$ bazel run //example:run 2>/dev/null
This is the bash script, about to call the counter tool.
This is the counter tool.
```

It's also worth mentioning this note ([from the docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#binary.args)):

> The arguments are not passed when you run the target outside of bazel (for example, by manually executing the binary in bazel-bin/).

Comment: MVP right here! This is the only solution that worked for me thank you

Comment: This works really well. However, if the `sh` file has a package that has been installed via pip e.g `celery` and you perform an action e.g `celery -A xxx worker -l INFO &> /app/logs/celery.log &` , you will still get an error about `celery`. Is there away to make `sh_binary` know about the installed packages? See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71602479/does-bazel-sh-binary-allow-calling-of-scripts-that-depends-on-some-pip-packages

Comment: Your sh binary can do anything it likes, including setting `PYTHONPATH`. But that would make your build non-hermetic, so you probably want to avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

An easier approach for me is to add the `cc_binary` as a dependency in the `data` section. In `prefix/BUILD`

```
cc_binary(name = "foo", ...)
sh_test(name = "foo_test", srcs = ["foo_test.sh"], data = [":foo"])
```

Inside `foo_test.sh`, the working directory is different, so you need to find the right `prefix` for the binary

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

executable=prefix/foo

$executable ...
```

Comment: That's also how you can depend on shared libraries created by some other target that you want to use in a `py_binary` or `py_library`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is no need to use rlocation for this.