# Does Bazel sh_binary allow calling of scripts that depends on some pip packages?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-java

I have the following `sh_binary`

```
sh_binary(
    name="worker",
    srcs=["worker.sh"],
)
```

and the `worker.sh` looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
celery -A twoopstracker worker -l INFO &> /app/logs/celery.log &
```

the `celery` has been installed using `pip_install` and can be depended upon by other `py_binary` using something like `requirement("celery"),`

Is there a way to make the `worker.sh` also have access to these requirements which will enable it to run successfully?
I can't add using the `deps = [requirement("celery"),]` since celery is a `py_library rule` and `sh_library` is expected.

is there a way to make the `sh_binary` use the installed `celery`?

I've tried the approach here